# How one can compute $\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t} t^{\pm \frac{1}{2}} \exp[ -x(t+t^{-1})] = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}} e^{-2x}$?

Tags: integration

For positive $x$ 
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{t} t^{\pm \frac{1}{2}} \exp[ -x(t+t^{-1})] = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}} e^{-2x}
\end{align}

How to compute this integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace $t$ with $u^2$, then $u-u^{-1}$ with $v$. This gives:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{1}t^{\pm\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left(-x(t+t^{-1})\right)\frac{dt}{t}&=&2\int_{0}^{1}u^{\pm 1}\exp\left(-x(u^2+u^{-2})\right)\frac{du}{u}\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(u+u^{-1}\right)\exp\left(-x(u^2+u^{-2})\right)\frac{du}{u}\\&=&e^{-2x}\int_{0}^{+\infty}(1+u^{-2})\exp\left(-x\left(u-u^{-1}\right)^2\right)\,du\\&=&e^{-2x}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-xv^2}\,dv\\&=&\color{red}{e^{-2x}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{x}}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Great answer(+1), but could you just clarify how you got from $2\int_{0}^{1} u^{\pm 1} \exp \cdots$ to $\int_{0}^{\infty} (u + u^{-1}) \exp \cdots$ and the change of limits.

Comment: @Mattos: if you replace $u$ with $u^{-1}$ you have that twice the integral in the RHS of the first line equals the integral over $\mathbb{R}^+$ that I wrote in the second line.